# AngularJS smart-table: Is there any way I can access the tableState without overriding stPipe function?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I need to store the tableState on my server so that when a user logs in later, I can show the exact table state that he/she left with all the sorting and filtering applied. Is there any way I can access the current tableState without overriding the `stPipe` function ?

Answer (score 2):

Found this useful plunkr for saving table state. I should be able to extend this to store the state on server instead of localStorage

http://plnkr.co/edit/ekwiNt?p=info

```
.directive('stPersist', function () {
        return {
            require: '^stTable',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                var nameSpace = attr.stPersist;

                //save the table state every time it changes
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return ctrl.tableState();
                }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                        localStorage.setItem(nameSpace, JSON.stringify(newValue));
                    }
                }, true);

                //fetch the table state when the directive is loaded
                if (localStorage.getItem(nameSpace)) {
                    var savedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(nameSpace));
                    var tableState = ctrl.tableState();

                    angular.extend(tableState, savedState);
                    ctrl.pipe();

                }

            }
        };
    });;
```